# Using a prerelease gem to satisfy a transitive dependency with Bundler

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, bundler, rspec-rails

I'm using RSpec with Guard, and targeting RSpec 3.0.0.rc1. `guard-rspec` has the following in [its gemspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/blob/v4.2.9/guard-rspec.gemspec):

```
s.add_dependency 'rspec', '>= 2.14', '< 4.0'
```

and in my Gemfile, I am specifying:

```
gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.rc1'
```

When I run `bundle update`, I get the following output:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rspec-expectations":
  In Gemfile:
    rspec (< 4.0, >= 2.14) ruby depends on
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0) ruby

    rspec-rails (~> 3.0.0.rc1) java depends on
      rspec-expectations (3.0.0.rc1)
```

How can I make this configuration resolve properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also add `gem 'rspec', '~> 3.0.0.rc1'` to your Gemfile